# What is the difference between 'autonomous' and 'automatic'?

Tags: differences

I would like to know the difference between

1. autonomous sensor
2. automatic sensor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous references on the internet to *autonomous sensors*.

[This article at IEEE Explore](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5475165) defines the term 'autonomous sensor'; it treats it almost as a compound term, and defines it more precisely than one would expect for 'automatic sensor'. In particular, it at least connotes the internal regulation (acquisition and conservation) of power, in addition to having the denotation *automatically performing the task/s intended*. More an organism analogue than a basic machine: self-regulating rather than just a one-trick pony.

> An autonomous sensor is a device that is generally able to perform its
> task without being connected to the interrogation unit. Its power
> supply is integrated in the device, and very often a harvesting
> mechanism is used for its energy production and is able to totally or
> partially power the device operation. There has been broad and rapid
> evolution in the field of autonomous sensors. Emerging application
> fields, the need to increase the life of electronic devices, increased
> computational capabilities that require more energy and drastic
> reduction in device volume have been drivers of this field. Power
> management and wireless connection are becoming major issues in many
> applications. Research communities all over the world are working to
> find solutions and harvesting methods to optimize the power issue in
> sensors with the specific goal of implementing autonomous sensors. We
> discuss these concepts and two examples: an autonomous sensing device
> and an energy harvester.

Comment: Fully agree ...

Comment: Thank you very much about the detailed information and the link. It helps.

Answer (score 2):

***Autonomous*** is normally used in relation to government. e.g. *The region is autonomous i.e. it has the freedom to govern itself and control its own affairs*.

I have never seen it used to describe a piece of equipment I am thinking that someone must have confused it with ***automatic***.

Comment: It's also (as a synonym of _autonomic_) used in biology: _existing as an organism independent of other organisms or parts_ [Collins]. The metaphorical broadening to machines other than plants or animal etc bodies is hardly earth-shattering.

Comment: at http://www.sunburstsensors.com/products/oceanographic-ph-sensor-benchtop.html , I found "the AFT-pH can run autonomously...".

Comment: Autonomous is commonly used of systems and products with some form of artificial intelligence such as [drones](https://www.propelrc.com/best-autonomous-drones/). It often denotes a specific set of functionality such as being able to operate without user intervention, although it's not a precise concept.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/autonomous) gives the various meanings of "autonomous".